# How to get array id and name values display in the same order on javascript after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an array in php which look like below:

```
    if(count($rows)) {
    $new = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $new[$row['id']] = $row['sel_date']." - ".date('l',$row['date_timestamp']);     
        //$myobj->id = $row['id'];
    }
}
```

Now on php page I have two option to pass my array back to the javascript ajax funtion:
either

> print_r($new) or echo json_encode($new)

However, when I send using json_encode($new) from php page to javascript page it lost the order of the php array keys.
so for example my php new array look like below:

```
Array
(
[71] => 07/09/2019 - Saturday
[81] => 08/09/2019 - Sunday
[83] => 09/09/2019 - Monday
[84] => 10/09/2019 - Tuesday
[72] => 15/09/2019 - Sunday
[73] => 16/09/2019 - Monday
[74] => 17/09/2019 - Tuesday
[75] => 18/09/2019 - Wednesday
)
```

Now on javscript side if I use JSON.parse(data) then the order will be like the below

```
Array
(
[71] => 07/09/2019 - Saturday
[72] => 15/09/2019 - Sunday
[73] => 16/09/2019 - Monday
[74] => 17/09/2019 - Tuesday
[75] => 18/09/2019 - Wednesday
[81] => 08/09/2019 - Sunday
[83] => 09/09/2019 - Monday
[84] => 10/09/2019 - Tuesday

)
```

Which I don't want happen as the json.parse rearranging the order of php array.

So what should I do to maintain the order and how I can loop through php returned array on javascript side so that my order remain same?

Thanks & was spending a lot of time to get this done but json.parse() is not allow me to maintain the order of php array and don't know any other way to loop through php array on javascript side.

Many people didnt get the answer right as I checked many other posts on stackoverflow but didn't get my answer thr. So please don't refer any other posts here.

Comment: returning data with `json_encode` is just pass data in json format, and not change the order of data.

Comment: that's strange as `json_encode()` never do re-arranging array data:- https://3v4l.org/duuMK

Comment: Do you need to keep the key values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_ENCODE` in PHP preserves the key order but the same is not true in Javascript.

In `PHP`:

```
$arr = [3 => "A", 1 => "B", 2 => "C"];
echo json_encode($arr);

Output:
{"3":"A","1":"B","2":"C"}
```

But if you try same in `Javascript`

```
var obj = {"3":"A","1":"B","2":"C"};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

Output:
"{"1":"B","2":"C","3":"A"}"
```

To preserve the key order in javascript too, you need to make the array of object in PHP.

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $newArr[] = [$key => $value];
}

echo json_encode($newArr);

Output:
[{"3":"A"},{"1":"B"},{"2":"C"}]
```

Now you can access same in Javascript.

```
arrObj = JSON.parse(str);

arrObj.forEach(function(element) {
    for (strKey in element) {
        console.log(strKey + ' : ' + element[strKey]);
    }
});

Output:
3 : A
1 : B
2 : C
```

Comment: i'd prefer this answer if preserving key is paramount, just add another nesting for key and value, its not uber complex adding it anyways

Comment: Included the way to access these key-value pair.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
echo json_encode($new,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: `json_encode()` never do re-arranging array data:- https://3v4l.org/duuMK

Comment: I was more likely looking for a solution on javascript side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` parameter to make [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) output an object. This will have keys in the output that will be recognised by javascript:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($new), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Output:

```
{
    "71": "07/09/2019-Saturday",
    "81": "08/09/2019-Sunday",
    "83": "09/09/2019-Monday",
    "84": "10/09/2019-Tuesday",
    "72": "15/09/2019-Sunday",
    "73": "16/09/2019-Monday",
    "74": "17/09/2019-Tuesday",
    "75": "18/09/2019-Wednesday"
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2d84N)

In javascript:

```js
let json = '{\
    "71": "07/09/2019-Saturday",\
    "81": "08/09/2019-Sunday",\
    "83": "09/09/2019-Monday",\
    "84": "10/09/2019-Tuesday",\
    "72": "15/09/2019-Sunday",\
    "73": "16/09/2019-Monday",\
    "74": "17/09/2019-Tuesday",\
    "75": "18/09/2019-Wednesday"\
}';
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj[72]);
```

Comment: May be op want's the keys for some purpose, otherwise why he specially mention it.

Comment: yes I want ID as well otherwise no issue but really thanks for your input.

Comment: @user2268488 see my edit. It will pass the key values through to JS as well

Comment: @Nick thanks for your help but found the right answer which I personally found quite simple.:) but I know 100 ways to resolve one issue, so thanks for your input as well and maybe if someone else is looking for a similar issue then they may like your solution.:)

Comment: @user2268488 I'm surprised you think the other answer is simpler. This answer involves one tiny change to your PHP code and none to your JS. But as long as you are happy...

Comment: Yes, @Nick I completely agree on this and I may use your code in some other part of my project as well as I am sure I need something simplified version as well. It's just I use the other answer because I already did a few things with what he suggested.